# How to connect phonegap app to server on broadcast address

Tags: ios, sockets, cordova, websocket, udp

I'm trying to connect a simple iOS Phonegap app to receive messages from a computer on my LAN that is broadcasting over 192.168.1.255 on port 4089.

As someone that knows nothing about this, what would be a good way to do this? Do I need to port forward anything? Would websockets be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no socket component is available on Phonegap library. You need to write native plugin for same. Since your computer is broadcasting the message, if you are on same LAN and reading the port 4089, you can read it. Websocket can work for it. SocketRocket is a good library.